# How to use the URL hash in a controller with UI Router?

Tags: angularjs, hash, angular-ui-router

I need to change a scope property for every change in state (or URL hash).
I am using `ui.router` and not `ngRoute` which is a problem.

I know `$location.path()` gives me the current hash, but it does not seem to serve the purpose. Below is a controller that I am using:

```
var myController = myApp.controller("myContoller", 
                                    ["$scope", "$location", 
                                    function ($scope, $location) {
                                        $scope.location = $location.path();
                                    });
```

The Binding that I bind in my view with `$scope.location` does not seem to be updated when a state changes. Is there a way I can capture a state change and probably 're-evaluate' the controller script?

Comment: If you really need this (which I really do doubt) then you can store just $location in your scope, and call path() on it: `$scope.location = $location` and in view `$location.path()`

Comment: I'll give it a try...
But that is not what I want, I would like to compute something out of the hash that I receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A post here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1699#issuecomment-11496428 seems to work great for what I want.

Basically, using a `$scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function (event) {});` helped.